# Confluence read database via REST API

Tags: confluence, confluence-rest-api

Confluence provides the new feature to create a database page:

[image: Add Database Page]

Now I would like to acces the data entered in such a database via API. Unfortunately I cannot find any documentation on how to do so.
I tried by expanding the body as described in following documentation. But this does not return any content of the database. https://developer.atlassian.com/cloud/confluence/rest/v1/api-group-content/#api-group-content

Also, in the official REST documentation I cannot find anything about reading databases. https://docs.atlassian.com/atlassian-confluence/REST/6.6.0/